# new to android - trying to understand java syntax: "append"

Tags: java, android

I am going through the following vogella tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview_example

And I came across this code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    Group group = new Group("Test " + j);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        group.children.add("Sub Item" + i);
    }
    groups.append(j, group);
}
```

I do not understand what `groups.append(j, group)` does... I understand everything else..

Comment: Where is `groups` declared?  What does the `Group` class look like?  This code CAN'T make much sense out of context.

Comment: Consider bookmarking the Android API docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append generally means "Put on the end."  For example if I was to append 1234 with 5 it would become 12345.  In your case groups appears to be some sort of storage/list (possibly some sort of hashmap) and when it does

```
SparseArray<Group> groups = new SparseArray<Group>();
groups.append(j, group);
```

It is likely adding new values to the end of the SparseArray groups.

Answer (score 1):

`groups` is of type `SparseArray<Group>`. You can check the javadoc of [`SparseArray.append()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html#append%28int,%20E%29)

Answer (score 0):

`appends` puts a new key/value pair into the "groups" SparseArray. Meaning you can access the added group via the key "j".

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html

Answer (score 0):

In the Tutorial vogella ads a Group Item to the gorups with key j(Integer) and Value group.
so he has this kind of object:

```
Groups
(j)1st: -GroupItem1
        -GroupItem2
        -GroupItem3
...
(j)2nd: -GroupItem1
        -GroupItem2
        -GroupItem3
 ...
```

Append inserts the Object at the and of the List

Answer (score 0):

Basically, expandable list is a list of lists. On code, it is treated as group of groups.

So on your case, **groups** is list, and each item of this list, is other **group**